# StoryBlok API returns unhandled runtime error 50% of time

Tags: next.js, next.js14, storyblok

Issue: Storyblok API **sometimes** returns unhandled runtime error when fetching page data.

Expectation: Storyblok API fetches data perfectly everytime.

Tech stack: Next 14, Storyblok, Tailwind

Docs used: https://www.storyblok.com/tp/add-a-headless-cms-to-next-js-13-in-5-minutes

Github : https://github.com/BryanMF87/bokeria

Online : https://bokeria.vercel.app/en

---

Details : I use the StoryBlokBridgeLoader on my root layout file for server-only data fetching

```
import { storyblokInit, apiPlugin } from "@storyblok/react/rsc";
import StoryblokBridgeLoader from '@storyblok/react/bridge-loader';

storyblokInit({
  accessToken: process.env.SB_TOKEN,
  use: [apiPlugin],
});

 return (
    <html>
      <body>
          {children}
      </body>
      <StoryblokBridgeLoader options={{}} />
    </html>
  );
```

Details: Each page I import and call the getStoryblokApi before data fetching

```
import { getStoryblokApi } from '@storyblok/react';

export default async function Home() {

  const storyblokApi = getStoryblokApi();
  const data = await storyblokApi.get(`cdn/stories/pages/home-page`, {
    version: "draft",
    language: lang,
  });
  const content = data.data.story.content;
```

Details : About 50% of the time when I try to link to another page I get this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'get')
```